# How does Integer become autoboxed into Future<Integer> when using Callable?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am using the Concurrency API, and I am passing an `instance` of a `class` which `implements Callable<T>` into the `submit(Callable<T>)` method to perform a task in a single thread.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

class myCallableClass implements Callable<Integer> { // Implementation of the Callable<T> interface
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception { // Clearly returning an Integer here, and yet ...
        System.out.println("1: doing first task");
        Thread.sleep(11 * 1000);
        return WaitingForAllTasksToFinish.counter + 2;
    }
}

public class WaitingForAllTasksToFinish {
    static int counter = 2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        ExecutorService service = null;
        try {
            service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
            Future<Integer> result 
            = service.submit(new myCallableClass()); // ... it can be assigned to Future<Integer> here!
            System.out.println(result.get()); // and I can use .get() which is a Future<T> method!
        } finally {
            if (service != null) service.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

To determine whether there is 'autobox', I tried to assign `Integer` into a `Future<Integer>`, but it was a compiler error:

```
Future<Integer> x = Integer.valueOf(4); // Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer to Future<Integer>
```

Question: am I right to assume that an Integer can be assigned to Future iif it is returned by the `submit(Callable<T>)` method? If so, is there something happening behind the scenes to accomplish this?

edits:

- changed 'autoboxed' into 'assigned'
- changed comment 'Callable' to 'Callable<T>'

Comment: "To determine whether there is 'autobox'" There is. If you return an `int` from a method whose return type is `Integer`, the result has to be autoboxed.

Comment: " am I right to assume that an Integer can be assigned to Future" You can never assign an `Integer` to a `Future`.

Comment: "it can be assigned to Future<Integer> here" What does "it" refer to here? You are assigning the return value of `ExecutorService.submit` (which is _declared to return_ `Future<T>`) to `result`. This is a totally different situation from `Future<Integer> x = Integer.valueOf(4);`, where you are assigning  the return value of `Integer.valueOf` (which is declared to return `Integer`) to `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the `Future` is not autoboxing. The Java language doesn't "know" about `Future` in the same way it knows about `Integer`/`int`. Autoboxing is specifically the language (compiler) automagically converting an `int` to `Integer` when appropriate.

What happens here is that an API (in this case [`ExecutorService.submit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.util.concurrent.Callable))) will return a `Future<T>` when passed in a `Callable<T>`. The ExecutorService will schedule the task for execution and return you a handle (the `Future`) that you can use to query if the task is completed and get the result from if necessary.

Note that there **is** one instance of autoboxing happening in your code, but that's at the line

```
return WaitingForAllTasksToFinish.counter + 2;
```

Since the method is defined to return an `Integer` but the expression `WaitingForAllTasksToFinish.counter + 2` is of type `int`, Java will automagically convert the `int` to an `Integer` for you, but this has nothing to do with creating the `Future`.